# Control validation against XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction.Facets

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have a a desktop application with a System.Windows.Form containing some TextBox controls. I need to validate the control values against restrictions of an xml schema.

For each TextBox I can retrieve the relevant  XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction from its type and then use a method as follows to validate its value:

```
 public static bool Validate(XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction restriction, string value)
    {
        bool isENum = false;
        bool isValidEnum = false;
        foreach (var item in restriction.Facets)
        {
            XmlSchemaLengthFacet lengthFacet = item as XmlSchemaLengthFacet;
            if (lengthFacet != null)
            {
                int length = Int32.Parse(lengthFacet.Value);
                if (!(value.Length == length))
                    return false;
            }

            XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet minLenghtFacet = item as XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet;
            if (minLenghtFacet != null)
            {
                int length = Int32.Parse(minLenghtFacet.Value);
                if (!(value.Length >= length))
                    return false;
            }

            XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet maxLenghtFacet = item as XmlSchemaMaxLengthFacet;
            if (maxLenghtFacet != null)
            {
                int length = Int32.Parse(maxLenghtFacet.Value);
                if (!(value.Length <= length))
                    return false;
            }

            XmlSchemaPatternFacet patternFacet = item as XmlSchemaPatternFacet;
            if (patternFacet != null)
            {
                Regex re = new Regex(patternFacet.Value);
                if (!re.IsMatch(value))
                    return false;
            }

            XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet enumFacet = item as XmlSchemaEnumerationFacet;
            if (patternFacet != null)
            {
                isENum = true;
                if (StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(value, enumFacet.Value) == 0)
                    isValidEnum = true;
            }
            if (isENum && (!isValidEnum))
                return false;


        return true;
    }
```

I am going to use this method in the Validating event of the controls. Is there any simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's a little more complicated than I initially thought. Basically, you need create an [`XmlSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that expects a single element with the provided restriction. Then you create an XML element with the provided value and validate it against the schema using an `XmlReader`:

```
    public static bool Validate(XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction restriction, string value)
    {
        var schema = new XmlSchema();
        schema.Items.Add(new XmlSchemaElement
        {
            Name = "value",
            SchemaType = new XmlSchemaSimpleType { Content = restriction }
        });

        var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemaSet.Add(schema);

        var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
            ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings,
            Schemas = schemaSet
        };

        string xml = new XElement("value", value).ToString();

        try
        {
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), readerSettings);
            while (reader.Read()) ;
            return true;
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaValidationException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I tested it with this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var restriction = new XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction { BaseTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") };
        restriction.Facets.Add(new XmlSchemaMinLengthFacet { Value = "3" });
        Console.WriteLine(Validate(restriction, "str"));
    }
```

Comment: The XmlSchema does not contain any Validate method.

Comment: You're welcome :). Just out of curiosity: Where are you getting the `XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction` from?

Comment: I get it by casting XmlShemaSimpleType.Content as XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction